# how to get selected value from wxlistbox

Tags: python, wxpython

i have a wxlistbox.i need to get the selected value from the wxlistbox
now i get only id from

```
self.lvnames.GetSelections().
```

but i need value instead of id.How?Please Help Me...

my listbox declaration is

```
self.lvnames=wx.ListBox(panel,-1,(10,40),(210,180),self.names, wx.LB_SINGLE)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
self.lvnames.GetString(self.lvnames.GetSelection())
```

You will get an error if you call this and there is nothign selected, so you can keep this in a `try... except` block

Comment: now my listbox is bind like `self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX,self.lvnameclick,self.lvnames)`.but while press down arrow an event takes place here.i only need single click event .not `EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK` please help me __Thank You Very Much__

Comment: why don't you post it as a new question?

Comment: i think this question may confuse others. __how to get wxlistbox single click event? Not EVT_LISTBOX event__ .Please help me. __Thanks__

Comment: please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569313/cursor-rowcount-gives-int-object-is-not-callable-error